# In android 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 when I am clicking any running application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

In android 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 when I am clicking any running application app icon then it again start from the beginning without opening that page where i have click the home button.Pleas help.

Comment: Application icon does not open last used activity..(In some situations (I do not know exactly what causes this to happen), If I start my app, open another activity and then click the home button to get to the phone home view, and then click the app icon from there, it starts in the application home view, instead of starting in the last open activity. Why is this and what do I need to do to make it return to the last used activity?)

Comment: Post your manifest. You can just edit your question and add the manifest to it. Please don't put the manifest in a comment.